# how can I solve the problem without using array as array is complicated to me for now?

Tags: c

Problem is :- Write a C code that ask the user to enter 10 numbers, then ask him to enter another number to search on it in the 10 numbers and print its location in case it is found. In case the number is not found, it will print number no exist.

Code I write is :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int n, i, value,j;

    for (i=1;i<=10;++i)
    {
        printf("enter number %d : ",i);
        scanf("%d",&n);

    }
    printf("Enter the value to search: ");
    scanf("%d",&value);
     /*next part of code is not correct 
        that can not search to find the place of number */
    for (j=1;j<=10;++j)
    { 
        if (value == n)
        {
            printf("value is exist at element number %d",n);

        }
        else 
        {
            printf("value is not exist\n");
        }

    }
}
```

output will be:-
(after enter the numbers).

```
Enter the value to search is 12.  
value is exist at element 9
```

Comment: Why the deuce can you not use an array?

Comment: Please learn how to format questions and read this: [ask]

Comment: You are storing all 10 numbers in the same variable `n`

Comment: It could be possible that your instructor might be wanting you to implement a linked list to illustrate that you can use different data structures then arrays. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/linked-list/ has some nice information about it : )

Comment: Did they tell you what data structure to use then? Probably, what data structure were you taught before getting this assignment. Start with a version which just stores the numbers user is entering. Once that works (or seems to work), then add code to print out all the numbers. Then as final step, instead of printing, do search.

Comment: You need to tell us everything. Did your instructor/teacher/tutor explicitely ask that no array should be used? Or do you simply think "arrays is too complicated for me, I want to do it without arrays", or... ? Please [edit]  your question for clarifications.

Comment: I had just taught ( if statement and for loop ) and that is it

Comment: The only way you can do this without an array is by using ten separate variables. (You can use a recursive function, but you haven't learned about those yet.) An array doesn't complicate it - if anything, it makes it easier.

Comment: The point of this exercise is that you get to practice the use of arrays. The point is not writing a program that produces a particular output. If you find arrays complicated, it is important for you to use one to solve this problem.

Comment: Solution: learn how to use an array. It's much easier than learning how to write code that avoids arrays.

Comment: Here's what I think happened.  The instructor wanted to show how hard it is to solve this problem using 10 separate int variables, 10 separate input statements, and 10 explicit if statements to "search".  The intent was to then *motivate* the use of arrays as a vastly superior alternative.  Such motivation is a fine, pedagogical technique -- *if* the instructor does it!  But expecting the student to come up with the "bad" solution which then motivates the better one is just bizarre.  Anyway, go easy on the OP -- this travesty isn't his fault.

Comment: If you want to do this without an array, it's actually easier if you also do it without any loops, either.  A loop is only good if you have an array to loop over.  If you have (say) ten individual variables, the easiest way to iterate over them is going to be with ten separate `if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    //there are 10 int in n
    int n[10], i, value;



    for (i=0;i<10;i=i+1)//array count from 0 ,i=i+1 same as i++ 
    {
        printf("enter number %d : ",i);
        scanf(" %d",&(n[i]));//& mean get address so you will push what you input to n[0]~n[9]
        //little tip  before %d remain a space for some reason if you keep learn you will know


    }
    printf("Enter the value to search: ");
    scanf(" %d",&value);//& mean get address so you push what you input to value here

    for (i=0;i<10;i=i+1)
    { 
        if (value == n[i])
        {
            printf("value is exist is element number %d\n",n[i]);
            break;//break mean out of for loop
            //
        }

    }
    if(i==10){//if search all not found then i will be 10 because after loop i will +1
        //if break i will not +1
        printf("value is not exist\n");
    }
        return 0;//remember "int" main() so you need return 0 
}
```

Keep learning you will be stronger
Array is simple